# LaTeX - Is it possible to write i and j as 'ij', where the letters are concatenated?

Tags: fonts

I want to write the i and j as one "ij", as can be seen in the Dutch language, in my LaTeX document, but can't figure out how to do it, even with ChatGPT! If someone knows more, please hit me up!

It could be the case that this is just not possible as it is not that frequently used, especially not when actually typing it. If so, please let me know too. Thank you.

Comment: just enter as ij the latex commands to title case etc will do the right thing treating ij as the first letter if the dutch localization is specified

Answer (score 2):

You should always type the `ij` and `IJ` as two characters, just as you would write `fi` and not `ﬁ`. The ligatures for these characters in the unicode standard are deprecated and should not be used.

If a certain font contains an ij ligature, it will replace the two characters with a ligature according to its own logic. Most fonts will do this when you activate the `lang=NLD` font feature, though this depends on the font (you might have to use a stylistic variant instead). When a reader selects or copies the resulting text, however, the ligature will be translated back into two characters.

Comment: Very interesting to read about this deprecated ﬁ Unicode character. Should you have a reference at hand, could you please consider providing a source/link?

Comment: @Alex see http://www.unicode.org/faq/ligature_digraph.html